# Making an unary operator binary

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators

I would like to overload the `operator~` but not as an unary operator but as an binary operator so i can do thinks like `a~b`. is there a way doing this in c++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421708/560648

Comment: If you want to invert each bit depending on the corresponding bit in a mask, then you can use the `^` operator; it's a bitlevel xor operation.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way of doing this in C++. Period.

Comment: Agreed! And it would make parsing the code challenging (at least) for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the behavior by [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), but you couldn't change the number of operands.

> It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or number of operands of operators.